# Join two TSV files with inner join

Tags: linux, shell, join, command-line, awk

I have 2 TSV files:

```
TSV file 1:
    A      B 
  hello   0.5
  bye     0.4

TSV file 2:
 C        D
hello     1
country   5
```

I want to join the 2 TSV files together based on `file1.A=file2.C`

How can i do it with the join function in linux?

Hoping to get this:

```
Text     B    D
hello    0.5  1
bye      0.4  
country       5
```

Not getting any output with this:

```
join -j 1 <(sort -k1 file1.tsv) <(sort -k1 file2.tsv)
```

Comment: Is your sample file1 really like that? Where are the tabs? Why are you sorting on `-k2`, but using `-j 1` to join? Also note in `man join` the `-e` option may help for non-matching items. Good luck.

Comment: This kind of worked for me. `join -t $'\t' -1 1 -2 1  <(sort -k1  file1.tsv) <(sort -k1  file2.tsv) > join_test.tsv` main issue i had was defining the tab delimiter.

Comment: Good catch and sorry I missed that key point. I'm glad you got a solution. And it never hurts to upvote those that have posted a usable solution. It gives people incentive to share what they know. Good luck to all.

Comment: What you're describing in your desired output is an `outer join` not an `inner join` as your title falsely suggests. I would recommend that the title be changed appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

A little hairy, but here is a solution using `awk` and associative arrays.

```
awk 'FNR == 1 {h[length(h) + 1] = $2}
     FILENAME ~ /test1.tsv/ && FNR > 1 {t1[$1]=$2}
     FILENAME ~ /test2.tsv/ && FNR > 1 {t2[$1]=$2}
     END{print "Text\t"h[1]"\t"h[2];
         for(x in t1){print x"\t"t1[x]"\t"t2[x]}
         for(x in t2){print x"\t"t1[x]"\t"t2[x]}}' test1.tsv test2.tsv | 
  sort | uniq
```

Answer (score 1):

**File1**

```
$ cat file1
A      B 
hello   0.5
bye     0.4
```

**File2**

```
$ cat file2
C        D
hello     1
country   5
```

**Output**

```
$ awk 'NR==1{print "Text","B","D"}FNR==1{next}FNR==NR{A[$1]=$2;next}{print $0,(f=$1 in A ? A[$1] : ""; if(f)delete A[$1]}END{for(i in A)print i,"",A[i]}' OFS='\t' file2 file1
Text    B   D
hello   0.5 1
bye     0.4 
country     5
```

**Better Readable Version**

```
awk '
     # Print header when NR = 1, this happens only when awk reads first file
     NR==1{print "Text","B","D"}

     # Number of Records relative to the current input file. 
     # When awk reads from the multiple input file, 
     # awk NR variable will give the total number of records relative to all the input file. 
     # Awk FNR will give you number of records for each input file
     # So when awk reads first line, stop processing and go to next line
     # this is just to skip header from each input file
     FNR==1{
             next
           }

     # FNR==NR is only true while reading first file (file2)
     FNR==NR{
              # Build assicioative array on the first column of the file
              # where array element is second column
              A[$1]=$2

              # Skip all proceeding blocks and process next line
              next 
            }
           {
              # Check index ($1 = column1) from second argument (file1) exists in array A 
              # if exists variable f will be 1 (true) otherwise 0 (false)
              # As long as above state is true
              # print current line and element of array A where index is column1
              print $0,( f=$1 in A ? A[$1] : "" )

              # Delete array element corresponding to index $1, if f is true
              if(f)delete A[$1]
            }

         # Finally in END block print array elements one by one,
         # from file2 which does not exists in file1
         END{
               for(i in A)
                   print i,"",A[i]
            }
    ' OFS='\t' file2 file1
```

Answer (score 0):

In your title you state you want to perform an `inner join`. Your example output suggests you want an `outer join`.

If you want an `inner join` as the title suggest, I recommend you use eBay's fabulous [tsv-utils](https://github.com/eBay/tsv-utils), particularly the [tsv-join](https://github.com/eBay/tsv-utils/blob/master/docs/tool_reference/tsv-join.md) command as follows:

```sh
tsv-join -H --filter-file 1.tsv --key-fields A --data-fields C --append-fields B 2.tsv
```

No awk magic needed, just a simple well documented command with easily understandable options.

The above produces a proper inner join, you'd just need to rename the join key to `text`:

```
C       D       B
hello   1       0.5
```